# my spawn point keeps changing everytime I die

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My spawn point keeps changing and always ends up right above a lava pool or in a cave... What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Is this single player or multiplayer? What version? Any client side mods? Any server plugins (if multiplayer)? Any other player suffer from this (if multiplayer)?  Do you see this only one one server or all servers (if multiplayer)? Have you placed (and slept) in a bed? You're going to have to work harder if you expect someone to be able to help you with this.

Comment: If you are in a server with whoever told you that you can summon a "super boss" they are probably moving your spawn point with op commands to troll you.

Comment: PLACE DOWN A BED. It will set your spawn to that location once you have slept in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are being trolled so hard and it gives me an idea but anyways if it is a single player put a **bed down and sleep in it but if it doesn't work make a spawn point.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a new server to play in.  You're being trolled.

If on the off chance this is single player, however, you're extremely unlucky and just need to use cheats to make yourself invulnerable long enough to create a new spawn point.